# fileinfo extenstion not working in xampp php7.3.11 windows 10

Tags: php, xampp, fileinfo

I have installed xampp 3.2.4 in windows 10 and php 7.3.11 
when  I go to upload image it shows

> Unable to guess the MIME type as no guessers are available (have you
>   enable the php_fileinfo extension?).

this error
in my php.ini i have enabled the extension  "`extension=fileinfo`"
I have attached image

[image: the image of my phpinfo() result]

Comment: did you restart the server after enabling it? I thin you did that's why it's being shown in phpinfo

Comment: the extension is already enabled
then I disabled it then again enable it then after both action i restart server